# Passing params throught pages with ui-router and angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I would like to pass an object to a controllerA to another controllerB and display that object. To do it, I'm using ui-router with angularjs.

This is my controllerA which build the URL using `$state.href()`:

```
const url = $state.href('home.stateA', {
    objectA: objectA
});

window.open(url, '_blank');
```

Now, this my route file:

```
.state('home.stateA', {
    url: '/stateA',
    template: '<template-b></template-b>',
    params: {
        // object: null
        objectA: null
    }
})
```

And finnaly, I try to get my object in my controllerB like that:

```
// $scope.object = $stateParams.object;
$scope.object = $stateParams.objectA;
```

When I `console.log` `$scope.object`, I'm getting `null` which is the default value in my route file.

So what's going wrong ? I'm wondering if `$window.open` would not be the problem.

Thanks for helping me.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use url parameter.

```
.state('home.stateA', {
    url: '/stateA?object',
    template: '<template-b></template-b>',
    params: {
       object: null
    }
})
```

Do when open new tab page

```
const url = $state.href('home.stateA', {
    objectA: JSON.stringify(objectA)
});
```

In controllerB

```
$scope.object = JSON.parse($stateParams.objectA);
```

Because when you are open new tab. The state param is lost

Comment: Can I still use `$stateParams` to get my object in the controllerB ? Because your solution did not work.

Comment: Can you `console.log($stateParams)`? I saw you set `objectA: objectA`? I think it should be `object: objectA`

Comment: Yes my bad, it was a typo. Actually it's dummy exemple in order to simplify my original code. However, my console log returns [object Object].

Comment: @BaptisteLinel: I edit my post, If you use object, you need to stringtify it, and parse when receive.

Answer (score 0):

```
window.open(url, '_blank');
```

You are opening a new window and trying to pass an object.

**Passing a String/Number**

You can pass a string/number say id, as part of the URL, if your state URL is defined like `'/stateUrl/:id'`
and then you can access this using `$stateParams.id`

**Sharing an object**

You can use [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) along with `JSON.stringify` and `JSON.parse` to share the object.

**Set data**

```
localStorage.setItem('object', JSON.stringify(object));
```

**Get data**

```
var object = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('object'));
```

Answer (score 0):

I have just found the solution ->

ControllerA

```
const url = $state.href('stateA');
let newTab = $window.open(url);

newTab.objectA = objectA;
```

ControllerB:

```
$scope.objectA = $window.objectA
```

And the state is very simple :

```
.state('home.stateA', {
    url: '/stateA',
    template: '<template-b></template-b>',
})
```

I don't know if it's the best way to implement what I needed but at least it works. it may help someone else.

Thanks guys and have a nice day !